# Connect two VM's in a data center

Tags: virtual-machines, hosting, ubuntu-14.04, traffic

I asked my hosting provider if I can use internal data traffic over http between two virtual machines I run with the same provider.

The short answer was, that this is not possible and the machines can only communicate over their static public ip. But no further explanation.

Now I am not sure, if this is technically generally not possible or the reason is, that those VM's might live in two geographically separated data centers.

Can anyone explain to me, if this could work or this is not possible in general?

Comment: Please leave a short comment, whats wrong with that question, if you downvote. Just trying to understand the matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's not possible because your provider said so. How can we know your provider's network architecture?

That said, it's trivial to configure an IPSec association (probably transport mode) between your two servers to allow private, authenticated, encrypted communication.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. I will see if I can configure private communication than, as you said.